# Openshift Origin on Digital Ocean adding new domains records issue

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, openshift-origin

I have an instance of openshift origin on digital ocean. Everything is working but when I create new apps it become a pain with DNS records. If I create a new domain, (php-test.openshift.example.com), the DNS record is not added to the zone file for the domain on Digital Ocean so when I try to access it I can't get anything. My solution so far has been to add the url to my /etc/hosts/ just before creating it and everything works fine but this is annoying. My question is has anyone run into this issue and how did you solve it? Did you have to make your openshift server be the actual nameserver for your domain (example.com) or were you able to hook it up to the digital ocean api using some kind of hooks system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default install expects that other hosts will resolve application fqdns using the installed DNS server.

To publish to an external DNS server, you will need to configure a DNS plugin, the nsupdate plugin configuration is documented here: http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html#configure-the-dns-plugin

There is also a route53 plugin (source code: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/plugins/dns/route53)

You could also create your own custom DNS plugin by using the nsupdate plugin as a template.

Comment: You could in theory have an authoritative server for your domain delegate DNS to your origin server. I don't know how you would do this in practice with a Digital Ocean subdomain. A DNS plugin is a fairly simple piece of code, and it looks like the API is fairly simple: https://gist.github.com/glpunk/8679208